# Доступ к странице только аутентифицированному пользователю

Tags: modx, php

Приветствую.

Вопрос к знатокам MODX Revolution (у меня 2.2.4-pl). Я вижу MODX, но не понимаю его.

На вкладке Resources есть страница Documentation. Захожу в редактирование. Вижу 4 вкладки:

1. Document
2. Settings
3. Template Variables
4. Resource Groups

Страница заполнена. На вкладке Settings включена опция «Freeze URI», а в поле URI указан адрес, по которому эта страница будет доступна.

Вопрос: как настраивается доступ к этой странице (проверка: залогинен или нет; достаточно ли прав для доступа к этому ресурсу). И **самое важное:** где определяется, что возвращать клиенту в случае, если доступ запрещен?

У меня вот есть 2 такие страницы: Documentation и Hello. Если я не аутентифицирован и пытаюсь зайти на страницу *Documentation*, мне вылетает 404-я ошибка. Если же я обращаюсь к  *Hello* — 403-я. А мне нужно сделать так, чтобы и там, и там вылетала 403-я.

Comment: Да, плохо, что нет у Хешкода кнопочки «UP», которую, скажем, можно было бы нажимать раз в час.

Я бы нажал в надежде, что уже пришли сюда люди, понимающие MODX. Не пришлось бы писать этот бессмысленный комментарий.

Comment: Можете про права почитать вот здесь: https://modx.pro/security/3776/
Есть ещё видеоинструкция: https://webdesign-master.ru/blog/modx/2016-04-04-modx-permissions.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Почитайте документацию, как настраивается доступ к страницам: [Making Member-only pages](http://rtfm.modx.com/display/revolution20/Making+Member-Only+Pages)

Comment: А где определяется поведение в случае отказа пользователю в ресурсе? В смысле, где этот параметр, который в одном случае отдает 404-ю ошибку, в другом — 403?

Еще я плохо понимаю значение словосочетания «Flush Permissions». Можно жать не опасаясь?

Да и вообще я очень слабо понимаю всю политику.

Comment: Прошу, добейте меня ответом: «Flush Permissions» — просто сбрасывает кеш контроля доступа? То есть, ничего плохого не произойдет, я не сброшу права доступа к страницам, которые реально закрыты сейчас?